# Class instantiated within another class - Beginner question

Tags: python, class, nested, instance

Sorry in advance for the very basic question, I'm approaching Python since few days.
I've looked to some other threads and while I understand why this happens I'm not sure I have understood the possible solution.

I attach here a short example of code snippet:

```
class Class_one:
    name = "First"

class Class_two:
    new_object = Class_one()

instance_one = Class_two()
instance_one.new_object.name = "Second"
instance_two = Class_two()
instance_two.new_object.name = "Third"

print(instance_one.new_object.name)
print(instance_two.new_object.name)
```

I see that Class_one gets instantiated only one time despite I'm trying to have two different instances associated one with instance_one and the other with instance_two.

The objective would be to have "Second" and "Third" as results of the two print instructions, while I get "Third" and "Third".

What would be the proper way of getting that result, still preserving a two-classes structure?

Comment: As long as the question is well-written, how basic it is does not matter.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3

Comment: I hope it was.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you used is for **class** variables, meaning ones that are shared among instances of the same class. In order to declare **instance** variables, you need to do it referring to an instance, e.g. using the `self` paremeter of instance methods:

```
class Class_one:
    name = "First"

class Class_two:
    def __init__(self):
        self.new_object = Class_one()

instance_one = Class_two()
instance_one.new_object.name = "Second"
instance_two = Class_two()
instance_two.new_object.name = "Third"

print(instance_one.new_object.name)
print(instance_two.new_object.name)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, was a silly thing but I could not understand it. Now it's clear. Appreciated!